# Decision tree with image border for each selected step HTML JQUERY CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a product configurator using the following script provided by Bill Miller from guiideas.com.

Link: http://www.guiideas.com/2013/09/interactive-decision-guide.html

I would like to change the text by pictures(and get rid of the summation signs) and add a border to the selected image.

Could you help me out?

Seem my edited code: https://jsfiddle.net/hUHQ2/234/

```
 $(this).addClass('selectedAnswer').siblings().removeClass('selectedAnswer');
```

Maybe adding something here to add and border to the selected image?

I'm using  tags now.

I would like to highlight the picture with a border when it is selected the same way the .selectedAnswer (red text) is done

Kind regards,
Dirk

Comment: Nice to know it. What have you do so far?

Comment: A few Google searches would answer your question. As per the StackOverflow guidelines please show you have at least tried to work it out yourself

Comment: The problem I have is that I want to remove the <li> tags. Because I don't want the summation sign.

The jQuery script counts these tags. That means I need to use different tags but I have to make sure that when I use this code in my original site that I don't have the same tags there aswell. So I tried using random tags for example<FAKE></FAKE> instead of the <li>. This way I am able to get rid of the summation sign. Now using an IMG tag instead of just text was easy. But the problem is that I want to highlight the image that is selected and remove a highlight when another selection is made.

Comment: You should give us some code showing your problem

Comment: Your question can’t be answered without relevant details. Rather than respond with a comment, you should edit your question to improve it. See [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$("IMGCLASSHERE").click(function() {

var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
$row.find("img").removeClass('activeBorder');           
$(this).addClass('activeBorder')
    });
```